# Can you add a photo from one shared album to another in iCloud using Mac Photos app?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

Assume I have a shared album A, and create a new album B. I would like to copy an image from album A to B.

It seems so simple in the iPhone Photos app, but I cannot find a way to do it in my Mac Photos app. While dragging the selected photos, I can see a green plus icon when I hover over album B. However, after I drag and drop it in B, there is no change?

How to do it? Is this some bug in Mac Photos?